# How can I display columns side-by-side with Flexbox or DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm converting an old HTML site which has this layout:

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

table {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 400px;
}

td, tr {
    border: 1px solid;
}

td img {
    width: 190px;
}

td img:after {
    content: "Image for illustration purposes only";
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stock list</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
        <td><b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3088/3127519858_8b75af8af5_z.jpg"></td>
        <td><b>1999 NISSAN MAXIMA 3.0 V6 GXE 4dr</b> blue <b>£500</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1276/919479405_86966cd5ec_o.jpg"></td>
        <td><b>1983 CHRYSLER E-CLASS 2.2 4dr</b> white, classic car <b>£3290</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the *after* pseudo-selector did not display the text.

This is what I am aiming for as a design (although with the white background):

[Advert design from magazine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvps5.jpg)

I'm aware about column-gap for spacing of columns.

How would I do this with DIV and either Flex or grid?

So far I've tried:

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

div.autota {
    display: grid;
    width: 320px;
    border: 2px solid;
    columns: 2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.autota img {
    height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autota">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
            <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
        </div>
        <div class="autota"><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3088/3127519858_8b75af8af5_z.jpg">
    <b>1999 NISSAN MAXIMA 3.0 V6 GXE 4dr</b> blue <b>£500</b>
        </div>
        <div class="autota">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1276/919479405_86966cd5ec_o.jpg">
            <b>1983 CHRYSLER E-CLASS 2.2 4dr</b> white, classic car <b>£3290</b></div>
```

And this hasn't quite come out looking like the image linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML content should look something like this:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-item">
     <div class="autota">
        <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
        <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid-item">
      Do the same as above for all items
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you can add CSS

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
}
```

And there are tons of different styles you can add to change the layout of your grid further! Take a look here once you've got the basic layout: *[CSS Grid Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)*

Comment: Please turn your answer into a working code snippet like the OP did

Comment: @LeeTaylor I have no idea how people do that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1):

You have to float the divs to the left. You should use percentage in width to make it responsive. I suggest you use some CSS framework, like [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), there isn't any need to reinvent the wheel.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

div.autota {
    display: grid;
    width: 320px;
    border: 2px solid;
    columns: 2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: left;
}

div.autota img {
    height: 90px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="autota">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
    <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
</div>

<div class="autota"><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3088/3127519858_8b75af8af5_z.jpg">
    <b>1999 NISSAN MAXIMA 3.0 V6 GXE 4dr</b> blue <b>£500</b>
</div>

<div class="autota">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1276/919479405_86966cd5ec_o.jpg">
    <b>1983 CHRYSLER E-CLASS 2.2 4dr</b> white, classic car <b>£3290</b></div>
    <br class="clear">
```

Comment: The original HTML was [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element). This isn't (e.g., hanging `</td>`). Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that kind of layout with Flexbox you could use:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="my_image"></td>
        <td><b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Into something like this

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><img src="my_image"></div>
        <div><b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Where in your CSS you would put something like this:

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: col;
    /* ... your styles */
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    /* ... your styles */
}

.col{
    width: 50%;
    /* ... your styles */
}
```

And that's about it. There isn't any need for external libraries of anything like that.

But of course, as you yourself said. This could be solved in an even easier manner with [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Please turn your answer into a working code snippet like the OP did.

Comment: @Sebastian Gudiño: It works, but for some reason, I tried grid-column-gap and spacing didn't work. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Intresting, how does it not work? Do you not see a gap? What if you try with just the "gap" prop? Do you get the gap working that way?