# Why does grid-gap not create a gap in my CSS grid layout?

Tags: html, css

Previous question with CSS: [How to display columns side-by-side with flex or DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468880/how-to-display-columns-side-by-side-with-flex-or-div).

This is the code for my div layout done in grid format:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div.autota {
  display: grid;
  width: 320px;
  border: 2px solid;
  columns: 2;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
}

div.autota img {
  width: 320px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="autota">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
  <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
</div>
<div class="autota"><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3088/3127519858_8b75af8af5_z.jpg">
  <b>1999 NISSAN MAXIMA 3.0 V6 GXE 4dr</b> blue <b>£500</b>
</div>
<div class="autota">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1276/919479405_86966cd5ec_o.jpg">
  <b>1983 CHRYSLER E-CLASS 2.2 4dr</b> white, classic car <b>£3290</b></div>
<div class="autota">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
  <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
</div>
<div class="autota"><img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3088/3127519858_8b75af8af5_z.jpg">
  <b>1999 NISSAN MAXIMA 3.0 V6 GXE 4dr</b> blue <b>£500</b>
</div>
<div class="autota">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1276/919479405_86966cd5ec_o.jpg">
  <b>1983 CHRYSLER E-CLASS 2.2 4dr</b> white, classic car <b>£3290</b></div>
<br class="clear">
```

This works functionally, but aesthetically, it hasn't quite worked, as there's no space between the DIVs with the class div.autota even though I declared grid-gap in CSS.

Would grid-column-gap be a better fix, or have I got my code wrong somewhere along the line?

Thank you for your help on my previous question!

Comment: Seems like you want a single parent grid container with a list of child cards. Here's a cool site to help you with that [Grid by Example: Usage...](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)

Answer (score 4):

The property `grid-gap` defines the gaps *inside* the grid, not between grids.

According to your style, each `.autota` is a grid of its own, and not a grid item. So your spacing actually does work, but it puts the gaps between the car `img` tag, and the `b` below it. Watch what happens when I turn it to 100px:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div.autota {
  display: grid;
  width: 320px;
  border: 2px solid;
  columns: 2;
  grid-gap: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
}

div.autota img {
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autota">
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/622/20721274966_b37363d59c_b.jpg"></td>
  <b>2014 FORD FOCUS 1.0 TITANIUM 5dr</b> silver <b>£6999</b>
</div>
```

What you probably want to do is make the **container** of each of the `.autota` another grid, and then set your gap on that instead.